# Invalid use of non-static data member from within a nested class

Tags: c++, class

I'm writing some code with polymorphic inheritance of two classes from a base class all nested within a class like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{

    class base
    {
    public:
        virtual void foo();
    };

    class B: public base
    {
    public:
        void foo() { cout << number1; }
    };

    class C: public base
    {
    public:
        void foo() { cout << number2; }
    };

public:
    A(unsigned num): number1(num), number2(num*2)
    {
        if(num < 5)
        {
            a = new B;
        }
        else
        {
            a = new C;
        }
    }

    void getNumber() const
    {
        a->foo();
    }

private:
    const unsigned number1;
    const unsigned number2;

    base* a;
};

int main()
{
    A object1(1);
    A object2(10);

    object1.getNumber();
    object2.getNumber();
}
```

From what I understand about c++11 and forwards, this should be possible? I know that nested classes post c++11 can access the data members of the class they are nested within as long as they have access to do so, but this seems to work against that. When I compile this I get these errors:

```
compiler commands: g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o t.exe

test.cpp: In member function 'virtual void A::B::foo()':
test.cpp:17:34: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::number1'
             void foo() { cout << number1; }
                              ^
test.cpp:45:24: note: declared here
         const unsigned number1;
                    ^
test.cpp: In member function 'virtual void A::C::foo()':
test.cpp:23:34: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::number2'
             void foo() { cout << number2; }
                              ^
test.cpp:46:24: note: declared here
         const unsigned number2;
```

This seems like it should work, as both B and C are nested within A and should have access to data members from A. Why is this? Is there a way to work around this feasibly?

Comment: "I know that nested classes post c++11 can access the data members of the class they are nested within as long as they have access to do so," - you are mistaken, the "nested class" is identical to having a non-nested class definition except that the name is scoped within the outer class.  A `B` object does not have any of `A`'s data members

Comment: Instances of class `base`, `B` and `C` don't have any magical pointer or reference to any particular instance of `A`. Just because `A` carries a `base*` pointer doesn't mean that `base` carries an `A*` pointer back. If you give these classes an `A*` pointer or `A&` reference, then they indeed can access `number1` and `number2` through it.